# Why don't changes made to a struct via a method persist?

Tags: methods, struct, go

I'm trying to understand why the following test code is not working as expected:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Test struct {
    someStrings []string
}

func (this Test) AddString(s string) {
    this.someStrings = append(this.someStrings, s)
    this.Count() // will print "1"
}

func (this Test) Count() {
    fmt.Println(len(this.someStrings))
}

func main() {
    var test Test
    test.AddString("testing")
    test.Count() // will print "0"
}
```

This would print:

```
"1"
"0"
```

Meaning that `someStrings` is apparently modified... and then it's not.

Anybody know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The AddString method is using a value (copy) receiver. The modification is made to the copy, not the original. A pointer receiver must be used to mutate the original entity:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

type Test struct {
        someStrings []string
}

func (t *Test) AddString(s string) {
        t.someStrings = append(t.someStrings, s)
        t.Count() // will print "1"
}

func (t Test) Count() {
        fmt.Println(len(t.someStrings))
}

func main() {
        var test Test
        test.AddString("testing")
        test.Count() // will print "0"
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/MaNh19CWe8)

---

Output

```
1
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your functions are defined on the object themselves rather than a pointer to the object.

```
func (this Test) AddString(s string) {
    this.someStrings = append(this.someStrings, s)
    this.Count() // will print "1"
}
```

The function above is defined on the concrete data.  This means that when you call the function, the value of `this` is passed in as a copy of the data.  So any mutations you do to `this` are done on the copy (in this case, the mutation is changing the pointer that 'someStrings' points to.  We can rewrite the same function defined on a pointer of Test as jnml did:

```
func (this *Test) AddString(s string) {
    this.someStrings = append(this.someStrings, s)
    this.Count() // will print "1"
}
```

As you can see, the function definition is `(this *Test)` instead of `(this Test)`.  This means that the variable `this` is passed by reference, and any mutations that take place are mutations performed on the original object.

Answer (score 0):

Go is going to pass everything by value. That includes function parameters, return values and when iterating over a slice, map or channel.

to add to @noj's answer if you switch your receiver to *Test type go will use a pointer automatically.